# First page takes a very long time to load in angular universal (SSR) mode

Tags: angular, rxjs, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm having a little problem with the initial loading of my site. I found the cause, but I don't quite know how to eliminate it.

I'm using angular 13 fired in SSR mode (angular universal)

So here goes:
my home page consists of 7 components(images,sliders,static content). I noticed that first load takes about 9 seconds. The reason is in one component which uses Swiper. If I turn this component off, the loading drops to 1-2 seconds.

The component itself looks like this:

Html:

```
<div class="whats-new">
  <div class="whats-new-bar">
    <h2 class="whats-new-title">News items:</h2>
    <div class="whats-new-type">
      <span>
        <i [ngClass]="{ active: premiumProducts }" (click)="showPremium()" class="premium-products">Premium</i>
        /
        <i [ngClass]="{ active: !premiumProducts }" (click)="showFree()" class="free-products">Free</i></span
      >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-section">
    <ng-container *ngIf="productsList.length > 0">
      <swiper *ngIf="config" class="swiper-container" [config]="config" #swiper>
        <div *ngFor="let product of productsList; let index = index" class="swiper-slide" #testChild>
          <div class="container-image" on-mouseenter="stopAutoplay()" on-mouseleave="startAutoplay()">
            <product-slide [product]="product" #relatedProductsItems>
            </product-slide>
          </div>
        </div>
      </swiper>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="nav-buttons">
      <svg-icon
        src="/assets/modules/home/whats-new/nav-arrow-left.svg"
        class="nav-button-left"
        [applyClass]="true"
      ></svg-icon>
      <svg-icon
        src="/assets/modules/home/whats-new/nav-arrow-right.svg"
        class="nav-button-right"
        [applyClass]="true"
      ></svg-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <a class="btn" [routerLink]="'/shop/all'"
        >LET'S SHOP
        <svg-icon src="/assets/icons/arrow-right-slim.svg"></svg-icon>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr class="section-break-quality" />
```

ts file:

```
export class WhatsNewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    public productsService: ProductsService,
    public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string
  ) {
    this.onResize();
  }

  @ViewChild('swiper') swiper!: SwiperComponent;

  @ViewChildren('relatedProductsItems') relatedProductsItems!: QueryList<RelatedProductSlideComponent>;

  public productsList: any = [];

  public productsListPremium = [];

  public productsListFreebie = [];

  public childItemslist: RelatedProductSlideComponent[] = [];

  public screenWidth!: number;

  public premiumProducts = true;

  public disabled = false;

  public config?: SwiperOptions;

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize() {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
   // if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.config = {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: 5,
        keyboard: true,
        mousewheel: false,
        updateOnWindowResize: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.nav-button-right',
          prevEl: '.nav-button-left',
        },
        breakpoints: {
          3000: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 25,
          },
          2500: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 25,
          },
          1930: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 10,
          },
          1500: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 40,
          },
          850: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 30,
          },
        },
        autoplay: {
          delay: 5000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        speed: 600,
      };
      this.productsService
        .getProducts({ ResultsOnPageLimit: '25', PageNumber: '1', OrderBy: 'newest_items', Type: 'non-free' })
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.productsList = response['results'];
          this.productsListPremium = this.productsList;
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });

      this.productsService
        .getProducts({ ResultsOnPageLimit: '25', PageNumber: '1', OrderBy: 'newest_items', Type: 'freebies' })
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.productsListFreebie = response['results'];
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });
  // }
  }

  startAutoplay() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.swiper.directiveRef!.startAutoplay();
    }
  }

  stopAutoplay() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.swiper!.directiveRef!.stopAutoplay();
    }
  }

  showPremium() {
    if (!this.premiumProducts) {
      this.productsList = this.productsListPremium;
      this.swiper.directiveRef!.update();
      this.swiper.directiveRef!.startAutoplay(true);
      this.premiumProducts = true;
    }
  }

  showFree() {
    if (this.premiumProducts) {
      this.productsList = this.productsListFreebie;
      this.premiumProducts = false;
      this.swiper.directiveRef!.update();
      this.swiper.directiveRef!.startAutoplay(true);
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed that when adding (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) { } in the ngAfterViewInit() method (in the code above it is commented out) the first page loads 3 times faster.

I think the problem is caused by loading data from the backend here:

```
 this.productsService
        .getProducts({ ResultsOnPageLimit: '25', PageNumber: '1', OrderBy: 'newest_items', Type: 'non-free' })
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.productsList = response['results'];
          this.productsListPremium = this.productsList;
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });

      this.productsService
        .getProducts({ ResultsOnPageLimit: '25', PageNumber: '1', OrderBy: 'newest_items', Type: 'freebies' })
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.productsListFreebie = response['results'];
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });
```

The endpoints themselves return data very quickly, they are not the cause of the problem.
In "ng serve" mode, the first page loads very quickly.

What could be the cause of this? Why does adding isPlatformBrowser verification speed up loading so much?

Comment: I had a same issue but it wasn't related to swiper

Comment: I've encountered this problem because of a running rxjs timer(10000)

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with loading time issues while using Angular Universal, too. What helped me, was indeed using the isPlatformBrowser option to make sure all the functions that require a browser window are only executed when it's available. Also, I wrapped my components in thematically structured feature modules to make use of the lazy loading feature in Angular.

I see you are using

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize() {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
```

&

```
updateOnWindowResize
```

'Window' is one of the things that breaks SSR, so you should check for isPlatformBrowser in this case.

Here is a link I found useful while figuring out how to improve page performance while using A-Universal: https://www.newline.co/@eigenjoy/angular-ssr-the-browser-is-not-the-server--2b398f60

Hope this helps :)